# Conditional Argument Expansion in Function Call

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, argument-unpacking

I want to conditionally replace a single line in a file, depending on some pre-conditions and write the new content.
The way i choose was:

```
n_file = []
For line in file.getlines():
    n_file.append( line.replace(
            *("foo", "bar") if False else
            *("baz", "bam") if True else
            # ...
            *("", "") # no replacement
    ))
new_file.write(n_file)
```

But i encoutered a Problem, that i dont understand.
**The Problems are the asterisks.** Whenever there are asterisks at the non-first position of the `replace()` function, it gives me a syntax error and i have absolutely no idea why.

You can try it for yourself. Its the same in Python 2 or 3.

```
def tf(a,b): print( str(a) +" "+ str(b) )

tf( *(1,1) if False else (2,2) if False else (3,3) )
# prints '3 3' as expec... intended

tf( *(1,1) if False else *(2,2) if False else *(3,3) )
# invalid syntax         ^

tf( (1,1) if False else (2,2) if False else (3,3) )
# missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

Though i found the solution for my particular problem. I still dont understand why it has to be that way.
My best guess is that it has something to do with the position of to-expand arguments but its still no explanation why the asteriks **has to be at the first item only**.

Kind regards.

ps.
This is my first question here and im not sure if the title is fitting (or how to specifically call this if-thingy, happening in `replace()`-args).
The search for answers about this problem was troublesome, so if u have a better title or tag suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Might be of related help to future readers of this thread based on the question in the title: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525530/where-does-python-argument-unpacking-fall-into-the-order-of-operations

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the entire cascade of ternaries with parentheses so those are evaluated first, then proceed to **unpack** the result of the expression. The *splat* operator stays outside the parens:

```
tf( *((1,1) if False else (2,2) if False else (3,3)) ) #-> 3 3
```

More specifically:

```
...
n_file.append( line.replace(
            **(("foo", "bar") if False else
               ("baz", "bam") if True else
                ...
               ("", "")) # no replacement
    ))
```

OTOH, code gets quite unreadable when you're cascading ternaries like so. Would be more readable to use a vanilla `if` clause, assign to a variable and then unpack the variable.